# Group by multiple columns with join

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables named bus, bustype, depo. The bus table contains bus name and foreign key from bustype (bustypeid) and depo(depoid).
Bustypes are SF,FP,LS etc and depo table contains different depos.

I need to get the list of buses grouped by depos and again group by bustype.

table - bus

```
busid   busname   depoid    bustypeid   
    1      KL-15 4567   7      1             
    2      KL-04-54     4      1             
    3      KL-02-11     7      3             
    4      KL-02-15     7      2
```

table - bustype

```
bustypeid   busname   
    1           SF           
    2           FP             
    3           LS
```

table - depo

```
 depoid       deponame
   7             depo1
   4             depo2
```

I wrote the query to group by bustypeid, that is

```
SELECT COUNT(busid) as availability,BS.bustype, B.depoid FROM `bus` as B inner join bustype as BS on B.`bustypeid`=BS.bustypeid GROUP BY BS.bustype
```

Now I need to again group by its by depo too.
The result might looks like ,

```
availability    bustype depoid  
1                FP     7
1                LS     4
2                SF     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add it to the `group by` clause:

```
 .... GROUP BY BS.bustype, depoid
```